# How to hide a control inside user control after click gridview button

Tags: asp.net

This is the problem that bothers me for the past few days

I have a page with couple user controls.

On that page, there is a grid. If a user click on a particular row, a control (li) on the user control is shown or hidden based on the condition.

What makes things complicate is the user control and grid grid are all inside the update panel, but another user control is outside updaet panel

In the rowcommand event, I assigned a Session variable, dontshow. Based on the criteria, dontshow variable will be assigned to true or false. Then the control on the user control will be shown or hidden based on dontshow condition

So far, I am encountering the problem.

let's say (li) control was shown, but after the user click gridview, dontshow is set to true. (li) control should be hidden. No it does not. I have to click other button to do postback to make it happen

The same is true for the usercontrol outside the update panel. The logic is similar

Over the past few days, I have found out that I can't set visible property of controls in user control at page_load because that happens after rowcommand event. I moved the code to pre_render event

I even tried to use different control such as placeholder, panel, etc. That still does not work
I also trace the code. The pre_render event comes after row command. dontshow variable is false. The (li) control visible is set to false. However, after rendering, I can still see the control

What should I do?

Below are the snapshot of the codes

Thank you for the help

main.aspx

```
.....
<%@ Register Src="../usercontrol1.ascx" TagPrefix="uctest1" TagName="ctrl1" %>
<%@ Register Src="../usercontrol2.ascx" TagPrefix="uctest2" TagName="ctrl2" %>
...

<ctrl1:uctest1runat="server" ID="test1" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepantest1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
   <ContentTemplate>

      <uctest2:ctrl2runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="test2" />
....

     <asp:GridView ...>
        //grid where rowcommand was executed
     </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

main.aspx code behind

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "something")
  {
      .....
      if (x = 1)
        session["dontshow"] = true
      else
        session["dontshow"] = false
  }
}
```

user control aspx  (usercontrol1)

....

```
 <ul>
  <li id="li1" runat="server">
    <asp:label>this is test</asp:label>
  </li>
  <li >
    <asp:label>this is test</asp:label>
  </li>
  <li >
    <asp:label>this is test</asp:label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

....
user control code behind (usercontrol1)

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool dontshow = false;
    if (Session["dontshow"] != null)
    {
       dontshow = (bool)Session["dontshow"]
    }
    if (dontshow)
      li1.visible = false
     else
      li1.visible = true
}
```

user control aspx  (usercontrol2)

....

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder1" runat="server">
<asp:label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

....
user control code behind (usercontrol2)

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool dontshow = false;
    if (Session["dontshow"] != null)
    {
       dontshow = (bool)Session["dontshow"]
    }
    if (dontshow)
    {
      label1.visible =false;
    }
     else
     {
       label1.visible =true;
       label1.Text ="this is test";

     }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the Visible property in Page_PreRender why don't you do it in gridview_RowCommand? Then you won't need to use a session variable.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do it on RowCommand, and it still did not work. By the way, I need to store in Session because when we navigate to other pages, we will know the status of conditions to determine whether to show or not. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some code how you did it?

Comment: As you suggested, I moved li1.visible = false (or true) statements to gridview_RowCommand. That did not work. I don't know why. It looks like it was too late to set visible after page_load event. Eventually, I wrote the jquery to change the visible property. I have to do in row_command. That kinds of defeat the purpose. I wanted to do it in user control. So far it has been working. I will cross my finger

Comment: Ok. If "li1" control is not part of the gridview try something like below in "li1" user control's code behind.

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    

    if (Session["dontshow"] != null)
    {

 if ((bool)Session["dontshow"])
  li1.visible = false
      else
        li1.visible = true
    }
}

Comment: Thanks!! over ride OnLoad, is that same as page_load event. If that is so, that was my first try. After debugging, I found out page_load event comes before row_command. Row_command is where Session["dontshow"]  sets. Then I moved the code to pre_render and redder. Those events come after row_command. Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to set visible condition (asp.net or jquery)

Comment: Try what I've suggested and see how it goes. You could also override OnPreRender like the same way

Comment: @Sam Thanks. onload on user controls happens before row_command. The condition is set. I traced the code. That obvious will not work . I tried OnPrender. All I did was replaced onload with onprender (changed in 2 places). It still does not work. I traced the code onprerender on user control happened after row_command on main page, but the result is still wrong. I have another user control. That has different the problem. The prerender does not event does not event after second postback. Now, the best solution is to code in the main page. Not what I want, but it works

Comment: I just realized all my user controls as well as grid are in grid. Don't know if that is the reason visible fails at pre_render

Comment: :-D That makes a big difference! That's why I asked in my earlier comment whether your "Li1" control is within a grid. Can you update your question and add the aspx code so that I could give you a specific answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Sam sorry about that. To be honest, I just realize that. I just modified the post to include the update panel. I also include the second user control. The OP did not because I thought if I can solve one, I can solve the other one. Then I realized things could be different if one user control is inside update panel, and the other one is not. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in your Row command like this

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "something")
  {
      .....

    var viewRow = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    HtmlGenericControl li1 = (HtmlGenericControl)viewRow.FindControl("li1");

      if (x = 1)
    {
            session["dontshow"] = true;
        li1.Visible = true;
    }
      else
    {
            session["dontshow"] = false;
        li1.Visible = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to hide the control during data bound you could do it like this

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl li1 = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("li1");

    if (dontshow)
            li1.visible = false;
        else
            li1.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Note that you should cast using the type of button you've used within grid view if you are using the rowcommand. I assumed you've used an ImageButton

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, that is what I am doing right now. I keep adding the user control codes inside the aspx. It works very well. The problem is I am finding more and more user control has the same issue. I keep adding. I am still hoping I can do in user control (more manageable), but at least your suggest will help me survive the release tomorrow. I really appreciate your help. I will still dig user control solution just in case I can't do it on other user control. Thanks again for your help all along

Comment: It's a pleasure! Let me know exactly what you are trying to do then I could shed some light. All the best with your release!

Comment: And, please accept this as the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: thank you for your help. Just vote your response as helpful. The reason I still don't want to accept the answer (not that your answer is wrong and not helpful) is I encounter couple user controls that I have to do it inside user control (still try to figure out how to do outside user control). I have done some research on user control update panels, so far I have no success. The hurdle is how to refresh the user control on update panel. Once I break through that bottleneck, it will a great help. Still appreciate your help

Comment: Ok no worries. If you post your ascx (user control) code and it's code behind I could have a look how you do it. And, make sure that you call the Update() method of the user control after you load. And, there are few attrib that you need to set in the update pannel like UpdateMode and EnableViewState. Let's see your code first.

Comment: thanks, I eventually made update panel work between 2 user controls. For now, I will be able to survive with that and updating the control on main page level. I know I will revisit the problem by making all the user controls work on update panels. FYI, http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/UsingUpdatePanelUserControls.aspx is link that I cloned for making update panels on user controls. Your advice on setting EnableViewState was helpful. I   failed to set that originally. That gave me big agony. Thanks for helping get through bottleneck

Comment: No worries. It's a pleasure to help someone. Cheers!